# Want to disable the whole class after i checked the check box

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, html

I want to disable the whole class after i checked the check box.

I'm having 2 options "upgrade now " and "upgrade later".

If i check upgrade Later, I'll get the options to time picker to scheduling the time.

If i check upgrade now then the schedule picker should be disabled.

How can i disable the whole class?

Below code is for the check box:

```
<div class="vcenter-domain-column">
                                    <div class="checkbox vcenter-domain-chkboxbtn">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="vcenter-1" name="vcenter-1" value="1">
                                    </div>
                                    <!--<img class="vcenter-domain-pic" src="img/cloud-icon.png">-->
                                    <div class="vcenter-domain-label">
                                        <label for="vcenter-1">Upgrade Now</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="vcenter-domain-column">
                                    <div class="checkbox vcenter-domain-chkboxbtn checked">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="vcenter-2" name="vcenter-2" value="1">
                                    </div>
                                    <!--<img class="vcenter-domain-pic" src="img/cloud-icon.png">-->
                                    <div class="vcenter-domain-label">
                                        <label for="vcenter-2">Upgrade Later</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

below code is for time picker:

```
<div class="update-schedule-section">
                        <p>Update schedule for all selected</p>
                        <div class="update-datepicker-section">
                            <div class="datepicker-box">
                                <span>date</span>
                                <input class="date-picker form-control" ng-click="open($event)" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="datepicker-box">
                                <span>Time</span>
                                <input class="time-picker" type="text" name="" value="10:00 PM">
                            </div>
                            <div class="datepicker-box">
                                <span>expected completion</span>
                                <span class="expected-date">Tuesday, Oct 7, 2014 - 2:00 AM</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: First of all you should be using radio buttons for this. What do you say?

Comment: yes you are right. I'll change this Our team has given this to me in a task. i'll change this to radio button. Thanks to remind me. And do you know to disable this?

Comment: i want both the codes? if you can.could you please provide that

Comment: Angular is not my cup of tea :

Comment: ok give me the jquery

Comment: Can you please update the question with `input type="radio"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the following code,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-checkbox-input-directive-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="checkboxExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.value1 = false;
      $scope.value2 = false;
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Upgrade Now: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value1"> <br/>
  Upgrade Later: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value2"> <br/>
  <div ng-show="value2 && !value1">Time picker</div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This will give you appropriate output.

Comment: If you find this answer useful, can you please vote as useful?